# Is there a way to quantify impact of independent variables with gradient boosting?

Tags: sas, random-forest, decision-tree

I've been asked to run a model using gradient boosting or random forest. So far so good, however, the only output that comes back in terms of variable importance is based on the number of times a variable was used as a branch rule.  I've now been asked to basically get coefficients or somehow quantify the impact that the variables have on the target. 
Is there a way to do this with a gradient boosting model? My other thoughts were to either use only the variables that were showed to be sued as branch rules in a regular decision tree or in a GLM or regular regression model.

Any help or ides would be appreciated!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make certain there is not a misunderstanding: SAS implementation of decision tree/gradient boosting (at least in EM) uses Split-Based variable Importance.

Split-Based Importance does NOT count the number splits made.
It is the ratio of the reduction of sum-of-squares by one variable (specific the sum over all splits by this variable) in relation to the reduction of sum-of-squares achieved by all splits in the model.

If you are using surrogate rules, highly correlated variables will receive roughly the same value.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!